# Filter duplicate filenames with tar

Tags: tar, wildcards, duplicate

I'm using tar like this,

```
tar -cjpvf a.tar "$pattern1" "$pattern2"
```

The problem is that pattern1 and pattern2 sometimes match the same file, but tar doesn't seem to filter these duplicates.

e.g The following example adds two duplicate entry in the archive

```
%> tar -cjpvf a.tar /etc/passwd /etc/passwd
%> tar -xvf a.tar
etc/passwd
etc/passwd
```

How can I filter them out?

Comment: Others are answering how to fix it (I would use `xargs` myself). For a quick *why* - remember that `tar` stands for tape archive, and is a format that can easily be appended to. So you could backup `/etc/passwd` today and then add `/etc/passwd` again to the same tape tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

If `pattern1` and `pattern2` are shell wildcard patterns then you can use an or-pattern.

```
tar -cjpvf a.tar @($pattern1|$pattern2)
```

This requires ksh, bash or zsh. In bash, you need to run `shopt -s extglob` first to activate the `@(…)` pattern syntax. In zsh, you need to run `setopt ksh_glob` first (and also tell zsh that the variables contain patterns rather than strings, so `@($~pattern1|$~pattern2)`), or use the native syntax `($~pattern1|$~pattern2)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you feel comfortable parsing the output of `ls` (and here assuming that none of the file names contain characters of `$IFS` or wildcard characters or start with `-`):

```
tar -cjpvf a.tar $(ls -d1 <pattern1> <pattern2> | sort | uniq)
```

or

```
tar -cjpvf a.tar $(ls -d1 <pattern1> <pattern2> | sort -u)
```

If you're not comfortable with parsing the output of `ls`, the right approach is to use `find` (here assuming GNU `tar` or compatible):

```
find -maxdepth 1 \( -name <pattern1> -o -name <pattern2> \) -print0 \
 | xargs -0 tar -cjpvf a.tar
```

(here assuming the list of files is small enough that only one invocation of `tar` is run. Also note that `find` doesn't omit hidden files by default).

Comment: `sort` has had a `-u` option for at least a decade now.

Comment: Cool. And I'm glad you added `xargs` too, because `find`'s `-exec` needs to die in a fire. ;)

Comment: @Aaron, that's at least 3 decades as the `sort` in PWB unix in 1980 already had it. There aren't many  good reasons of  preferring `xargs` over `-exec` and many to prefer `-exec` over `xargs`. See also [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Answer (score 0):

If the order matters. For instance, if you want to archive `foo*` and `*.txt` files, and you want the `foo*` files to appear first in the archive (but `foo.txt` not to be included twice). IOW, get `foo.a` `foo.b` `foo.txt` `foo.z` `a.txt` `b.txt` `z.txt` in that order:

With `zsh`:

```
files=(./foo*(N) ./*.txt(N))
(($#files)) && tar jcf file.tar.bz2 ${(u)files}
```

With `tcsh`:

```
set -f files = (./foo* ./*.txt) && tar jcf file.tar.gz2 $files:q
```

If you want to make sure the `*.txt` are last (`foo.a` `foo.b` `foo.z` `a.txt` `b.txt` `foo.txt` `z.txt` in that order):

With `zsh`:

```
files=(./foo*(N) ./*.txt(N))
(($#files)) && tar jcf file.tar.bz2 ${(uOa)${(Oa)files}}
```

(`Oa` being a parameter expansion flag that reverses the order of the array)

With `tcsh`:

```
set -l files = (./foo* ./*.txt) && tar jcf file.tar.gz2 $files:q
```